# Formal Language vs First Order Language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

My book, when speaks about the "First Order Logic" calls it "language". This term can be used also to denote a sub-set of this language or it can only be used to denote things like:
-First order language
-propositional language
-second order language

??

Comment: "my book" ?????

Comment: You may review some introductory material; see e.g. [First-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) is made of:

> *(i)* a *language*, made of
>
> > *(i.a)* an *alphabet*: a set (usually finite) of *symbols*, and
> >
> > *(i.b)* a *grammar*: a set of rules which tell how some expressions are *well-formed* (i..e. meaningful);

and:

> *(ii)* a *proof system* (or *calculus*), made of
>
> > *(ii.a)* a set of "special" formulas: the *axioms*, and
> >
> > *(ii.b)* a set of *inference rules*.

[First-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) (or *predicate calculus*) is a proof system based on first-order language, i.e. the language having as *logical symbols*, in addition to the (propositional) *connectives*, also the *quantifiers* and the (individual) *variables*.

It is called "first-order" because quantification is allowed on individual variables only.

When quantification is allowed also on predicate variables, we call it [Higher-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_logic).